# MAC tag size in AES CCM, when using CTR + CBC-MAC (not CBC MAC only)

Tags: authentication, cbc-mac, ccm

Assuming that AES CCM is used with respect of the NONCE unicity // the key life cycle, I wonder about the need of using the highest size for CBC-MAC authentication tag if CTR mode encrypts both payload AND authentication tag :

If no encryption is performed (e.g AES CBC MAC only), I understand the need of highest tag, i.e 128 bits , thus to prevent from brute force attack .

But : if the tag is ciphered using CTR mode as the payload is, I guess it guarantee that an adversary can not pickup any pair (Plain text / tag) and try to get another pair that matches ?

Any suggestions welcome, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

There are different "brute force" attacks related to CBC-MAC:

1. Key search, which depends on key size and not the length of the authentication tag.
2. Tag guessing, where you just try a random tag for a modified message succeeds with probability $2^{-t}$ if the tag is $t$ bits long.

The first is not related to the tag length at all and even if you use AES-128 you are secure from it. (As long as it's a random key, anyway: e.g. a password derived key could still be guessed with a non-brute force attack.)

The second works the same whether you use plain CBC-MAC (with prefix free messages) or in CCM where the authentication tag is encrypted. By using a tag smaller than 128 bits you increase the probability of the attacker creating a correct tag at random. Whether the tag is encrypted or not, the probability is always $2^{-t}$.

Where the encryption *may* matter is [security after the birthday bound](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8746/13625). CCM may offer authenticity even after you have used the key too many times to offer full privacy (i.e. close to $2^{64}$ blocks). Even there the tag length gives an upper bound for security, so that fact does not justify using a shorter tag.

None of that means you must use a 128-bit tag, of course. Forging a 64-bit tag, for example, would be very unlikely. It comes down to how sure you want to be about authenticity.